# Execution commands with input redirection operator in Java

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

I am trying to send a mail from Unix shell through a java program. I use Apache commons exec to do this.

The command is

```
mutt  -s "Subject of mail" email@domain.com < file.txt
```

And the Java code I use is

```
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse("mutt");
cmdLine.addArgument("-s");
cmdLine.addArgument("Subject of mail");
cmdLine.addArgument("email@domain.com");
cmdLine.addArgument("<");
cmdLine.addArgument("file.txt");
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
int exitValue = 0;
try {
    exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this code does not work. How to do input redirection using java

Answer (score 2):

Try
 `executor.getStreamHandler().setProcessInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.txt"))`

but take care of the filepath

Comment: Thanks Turo. What should be the parameter for setProcessInputStream? I am new to Apache exec.